# getting error in paypal subscription code, error : 10474

Tags: php, paypal

I am using paypal subscription script that allow user to subscribe products.
But when im trying to execute it, it will return with this error

```
string(506) "METHOD=CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile&VERSION=64&PWD={PWD}&USER={USER}&SIGNATURE={SIGNATURE}&TOKEN={TOKEN}=bluezeal+softnet&SHIPTOSTREET=kolkata&SHIPTOCITY=kolkata&SHIPTOSTATE=West+Bengal&SHIPTOZIP=700114&SHIPTOCOUNTRY=IN&PROFILESTARTDATE=2011-07-01T0%3A0%3A0&DESC=Test+Recurring+Payment%28%241+monthly%29&BILLINGPERIOD=Month&BILLINGFREQUENCY=5&AMT=1&CURRENCYCODE=USD&IPADDRESS=::1&BUTTONSOURCE=PP-ECWizard" GetExpressCheckoutDetails API call failed. Detailed Error Message: This transaction cannot be processed. The country code in the shipping address must match the buyer's country of residence.Short Error Message: Invalid DataError Code: 10474Error Severity Code: Error
```

Anyone have any idea regarding this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: _“The country code in the shipping address must match the buyer's country of residence”_ – that looks like plain and simple English to me … so what exactly is your problem understanding this?

Comment: @CBroe no thats not issue, but how can i set country code and what country code i need to set? i think it taking from paypal. not hardcoded

Comment: Well looks like you need to find out the buyer's country of residence first. (Or maybe you don’t need an actual shipping address, depending on the nature of the subscription resp. products it contains …?)

Comment: no it doesn't  need shipping, its virtual product

Comment: @CBroe even i removed `$nvpstr.="&SHIPTOSTREET=".$shipToStreet;
  $nvpstr.="&SHIPTOCITY=".$shipToCity;
  $nvpstr.="&SHIPTOSTATE=".$shipToState;
  $nvpstr.="&SHIPTOZIP=".$shipToZip;
  $nvpstr.="&SHIPTOCOUNTRY=".$shipToCountry;` from request. buts till same error

Answer (score 0):

if you sell virtual product, please remove all shipping address related parameters from setexpresscheckout API request. In SetExpressCheckout API, set NOSHIPPING =1 (don't request a shipping address), then try again.